# Problem after uninstalling service when asking for restart - WHY?

Tags: c#, windows, service, uninstallation, setup-project

i have had a problem with some self-programmed windows services for some time. The Windows services are built and installed by the Visual-Studio own setup project. Since some time there is a prompt after uninstalling these services that the system has to be restarted
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG8zr.png).
If you do not restart the system, install the new version of the service, this service will only run until the system is restarted. After restarting, the exe file is suddenly missing in the installation folder. So you are forced to restart Windows after uninstalling the service. Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: might be that the file is in use, do you stop the service before uninstalling it?

Comment: Yes I stopped the service manually before uninstalling service. Is it possible to find out which files are in use or which file using occurs this prompt?

Comment: Process explorer can be useful to check for files that are used. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: Thank you, Jonas, I downloaded this app, but there is only one entry of the running service (.exe), no further used files of these process. I tried to stop the service to find out, if something stayed open, but the only one entry oof the exe disappears as expected when stopping the service. :(